# Replacing outliers with SD value above & below the mean

Tags: r, statistics, data-cleaning, imputation

I have a log transformed dataset of reaction times here. There are 100 columns representing the trials and 160 participants. I want to replace values 2.5 SDs above and below the mean with values that are *exactly* 2.5 SDs above and below the mean without having to manually calculate the values for each column.

So, for example let's say the first column/variable is "r1" with 160 reaction times with the following descriptives:

- Mean = -.0871
- SD = .368
- +2.5 SD = .833
- -2.5 SD = -1.007

I want to replace every value in the column "r1" above .833 with .833 and every value below -1.007 with -1.007. Of course, I want to do this for every column. I realize that I may have to have a line of code for each column, but that should be fine.

Simpler Example:

```
r1 <- c(2,1,3,2,3,10,2,2,NA,1,1)

r2 <- c(3,2,1,2,3,-12,4,1,1,1,1)

r3 <- c(7,1,1,2,1,3,2,1,3,1,1)

r4 <- c(3,3,1,1,2,5,1,1,2,1,1)

df <- data.frame(r1,r2,r3,r4)

describe(df)
```

In this example, the outliers in each column (> or < 2.5 SD above and below the mean) need to be replaced with values that are exactly 2.5 SD above and below the mean respectively (like the -12 in "r2" and "10" in "r1" would need replacing).

```
   df$r1 <- lapply(df$r1, function(x){
  if(x > mean(df$r1) + 2.5 * sd(df$r1))
  {mean(df$r1) + 2.5 * sd(df$r1)}
  else if (x < mean(df$r1) - 2.5 * sd(df$r1)) 
  {mean(df$r1) - 2.5 * sd(df$r1)}
  else {x}
})
```

As suggested below, this works with columns that don't have missing data (i.e., "r2"), but I need to leave the data as missing.

Comment: Can you give an example dataset and show the result that you want?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that might be what you're looking for:

```
data$column <- lapply(col, function(X){
  if(X > mean(col) + 2.5 * sd(col)){mean(col) + 2.5 * sd(col)}
  else if (X < mean(col) - 2.5 * sd(col)) {mean(col) - 2.5 * sd(col)}
  else {X}
})
```

or you could use a nested ifelse function.  ifelse applies the given test for each item in the list and returns a list of the same size with each result.

That is, if I'm understanding the question correctly.

There may possibly exist more elegant solutions...

Comment: Hmm Seems to be giving me this errorError in if (x > mean(col) + 2.5 * sd(col)) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: This does work for the example data. I'll see if I can get it happen for the real dataset